# Limit decimals to three digits laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Previous Code

```
$product->selling_price
```

Result 1.1000

I tried

```
({{ ceil($product->selling_price) }})
```

1

I want 1.100 (for Kuwait dinar)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `number_format`

```
number_format((float)$product->selling_price, 3, '.')
```

PHP official documentation

> number_format ( float $num , int $decimals = 0 , string|null
> $decimal_separator = "." , string|null $thousands_separator = "," ) :
> string
>
> Formats a number with grouped thousands and optionally decimal
> digits.

Ref:https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: {{ number_format((float)$product->selling_price, 3, '.', '') }}

Answer (score 0):

Try This One: I have solved using this:

```
 number_format((float)$product->payable_amount, 2,)
```